# Reducing boot time

Tags: boot, drivers, kernel, time

I am trying to reduce my boot time for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS as much as possible. What are the possible ways to get a list of unnecessary modules that are being loaded on boot?

EDIT: 
`systemd-analyze blame` output :

```
     3min 495ms powerd.service
     18.974s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
     15.514s ModemManager.service
     14.454s dev-sda2.device
     14.223s grub-common.service
     14.216s irqbalance.service
     14.203s cpufreqd.service
     14.184s apport.service
     13.644s networking.service
     13.259s accounts-daemon.service
     13.077s speech-dispatcher.service
     13.010s linuxlogo.service
     12.434s systemd-logind.service
     12.413s apmd.service
     12.392s sddm.service
     12.390s sysstat.service
     12.371s aksusbd.service
     12.366s ondemand.service
     12.365s rsyslog.service
     12.359s pppd-dns.service
     12.353s click-system-hooks.service
     12.352s gpu-manager.service
     12.343s lm-sensors.service
     12.341s systemd-user-sessions.service
     12.340s cgroupfs-mount.service
     12.333s alsa-restore.service
     12.319s bluetooth.service
     12.309s iio-sensor-proxy.service
     11.539s ufw.service
     11.380s avahi-daemon.service
     11.377s thermald.service
      5.141s apparmor.service
      4.257s qemu-kvm.service
      4.209s nmbd.service
      4.147s NetworkManager.service
      3.567s sensord.service
      3.313s quota.service
      2.981s systemd-udevd.service
      2.639s apt-daily.service
      2.254s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
      2.235s keyboard-setup.service
      2.137s kannel.service
      1.775s lightdm.service
      1.643s dev-loop0.device
      1.621s console-setup.service
      1.517s dev-loop1.device
      1.466s dev-hugepages.mount
      1.463s dev-loop2.device
      1.405s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-14DD\x2d2000.service
      1.271s binfmt-support.service
      1.266s dev-mqueue.mount
      1.259s sys-kernel-debug.mount
      1.222s polkitd.service
      1.185s boot-efi.mount
      1.106s systemd-journald.service
      1.049s systemd-modules-load.service
      1.021s systemd-journal-flush.service
       713ms systemd-random-seed.service
       653ms ofono.service
       642ms snap-core-4327.mount
       630ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
       620ms snap-core-4206.mount
       591ms snap-core-4110.mount
       558ms dns-clean.service
       554ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
       551ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
       475ms ntp.service
       453ms resolvconf.service
       444ms user@1000.service
       442ms dev-sda3.swap
       392ms systemd-update-utmp.service
       380ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
       350ms tlp.service
       346ms systemd-sysctl.service
       251ms ssh.service
       236ms setvtrgb.service
       216ms sys-kernel-config.mount
       214ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
       202ms docker.socket
       193ms kmod-static-nodes.service
       168ms smbd.service
       164ms wpa_supplicant.service
       151ms systemd-remount-fs.service
       149ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
       120ms hddtemp.service
        32ms rc-local.service
        17ms plymouth-read-write.service
         7ms rtkit-daemon.service
         6ms postfix.service
         6ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
         5ms ureadahead-stop.service
         4ms ubuntu-fan.service
         3ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
         3ms vsftpd.service
```

Comment: Please add output of `systemd-analyze blame` to the question.

Comment: Output added @N0rbert

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not know what to do with `powerd.service`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some information about that here.  https://bugs.launchpad.net/powerd/+bug/1443278  On that page they say how to disable the service with

```
sudo systemctl disable powerd.service
```

Comment: I disable and later on uninstalled powerd, the boot time is significantly lesser now. Thanks!!